# How to Encrypt/Secure MS Access 2007 database file in C#?

Tags: c#, cryptography, ms-access-2007

I have a program which let me access/add/delete entries from MS Access 2007 file by using a simple database password.

But my goal is to modify my file so it would be much more secure. I want to encrypt my file, if possible with encryption chosen by user, and make it accessible only if user provide correct username and password.

How would I do this? How do I encrypt file? How can I make it so user can authenticate?

Please be specific, and examples for dummies preferred :)

**EDIT: Would that be more secure if I would encrypt every entry in the file using AES? Should I do this and let the database file with no password?**

This is how I am accessing a file at this moment:

```
// May be public so we can display
// content of file from different forms.
public void DisplayFileContent(string filePath)
{
    // Creating an object allowing me connecting to the database.
    OleDbConnection objOleDbConnection = new OleDbConnection();
    // Creating command object.
    objOleDbConnection.ConnectionString =
        "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
        "Data Source=" + filePath + ";" +
        "Persist Security Info=False;" +
        "Jet OLEDB:Database Password=" + storedAuth.Password + ";";
    OleDbCommand objOleDbCommand = new OleDbCommand();
    objOleDbCommand.Connection = objOleDbConnection;
    objOleDbCommand.CommandText = "Select * FROM PersonalData";

    // Create a data reader.
    OleDbDataReader readPersonalData;

    try
    {
        // Open database connection.
        objOleDbConnection.Open();

        // Associate data reader with the command.
        readPersonalData = objOleDbCommand.ExecuteReader();

        // Counting all entries.
        int countEntries = 0;

        // Clearing the textbox before proceeding.
        txtDisplay.Text = string.Empty;

        if (readPersonalData.HasRows)
        {
            while (readPersonalData.Read())
            {
                // Count all entries read from the reader.
                countEntries++;

                txtDisplay.Text += "=== Entry ID: " + readPersonalData.GetValue(0) + " ===" + Environment.NewLine;
                txtDisplay.Text += "Type: " + readPersonalData.GetValue(1) + Environment.NewLine;
                if (!readPersonalData.IsDBNull(2)) txtDisplay.Text += "URL: " + readPersonalData.GetValue(2) + Environment.NewLine;
                if (!readPersonalData.IsDBNull(3)) txtDisplay.Text += "Software Name: " + readPersonalData.GetValue(3) + Environment.NewLine;
                if (!readPersonalData.IsDBNull(4)) txtDisplay.Text += "Serial Code: " + readPersonalData.GetValue(4) + Environment.NewLine;
                if (!readPersonalData.IsDBNull(5)) txtDisplay.Text += "User Name: " + readPersonalData.GetValue(5) + Environment.NewLine;
                if (!readPersonalData.IsDBNull(6)) txtDisplay.Text += "Password: " + readPersonalData.GetValue(6) + Environment.NewLine;
                txtDisplay.Text += Environment.NewLine;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            txtDisplay.Text = "There is nothing to display! You must add something so I can display something here.";
        }

        // Displaying number of entries in the status bar.
        tsslStatus.Text = "A total of " + countEntries + " entries.";

        // Selecting 0 character to make sure text
        // isn't completly selected.
        txtDisplay.SelectionStart = 0;
    }
```

My EncryptDecrypt.cs file:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace Password_Manager
{
    class EncryptDecrypt
    {
        string input, userName, password;

        RijndaelManaged Crypto = new RijndaelManaged();

        public EncryptDecrypt()
        {
        }

        public EncryptDecrypt(string input, string userName, string password)
        {
            this.input = input;
            this.userName = userName;
            this.password = password;
        }

        public string Encrypt(string PlainText, string pass, string usrName)
        {
            string HashAlgorithm = "SHA1"; 
            int PasswordIterations = 2;
            string InitialVector = "OFRna73m*aze01xY";
            int KeySize = 256;

            this.input = PlainText;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(PlainText))
                return "";

            byte[] InitialVectorBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(InitialVector);
            byte[] SaltValueBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(usrName);
            byte[] PlainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(PlainText);

            PasswordDeriveBytes DerivedPassword = new PasswordDeriveBytes(pass, SaltValueBytes, HashAlgorithm, PasswordIterations);

            byte[] KeyBytes = DerivedPassword.GetBytes(KeySize / 8);

            RijndaelManaged SymmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged();

            SymmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

            byte[] CipherTextBytes = null;

            using (ICryptoTransform Encryptor = SymmetricKey.CreateEncryptor(KeyBytes, InitialVectorBytes))
            {
                using (MemoryStream MemStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (CryptoStream CryptoStream = new CryptoStream(MemStream, Encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        CryptoStream.Write(PlainTextBytes, 0, PlainTextBytes.Length);
                        CryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
                        CipherTextBytes = MemStream.ToArray();
                        MemStream.Close();
                        CryptoStream.Close();
                    }
                }
            }

            SymmetricKey.Clear();
            return Convert.ToBase64String(CipherTextBytes);
        }

        public string Decrypt(string CipherText, string pass, string usrName)
        {
            string HashAlgorithm = "SHA1"; 
            int PasswordIterations = 2;
            string InitialVector = "OFRna73m*aze01xY";
            int KeySize = 256;

             if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(CipherText))
                 return "";

             byte[] InitialVectorBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(InitialVector);

             byte[] SaltValueBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(usrName);
             byte[] CipherTextBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(CipherText);

             PasswordDeriveBytes DerivedPassword = new PasswordDeriveBytes(pass, SaltValueBytes, HashAlgorithm, PasswordIterations);

             byte[] KeyBytes = DerivedPassword.GetBytes(KeySize / 8);

             RijndaelManaged SymmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged();

             SymmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

             byte[] PlainTextBytes = new byte[CipherTextBytes.Length];

             int ByteCount = 0;

             using (ICryptoTransform Decryptor = SymmetricKey.CreateDecryptor(KeyBytes, InitialVectorBytes))
             {
                 using (MemoryStream MemStream = new MemoryStream(CipherTextBytes))
                 {

                     using (CryptoStream CryptoStream = new CryptoStream(MemStream, Decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                     {
                         ByteCount = CryptoStream.Read(PlainTextBytes, 0, PlainTextBytes.Length);
                         MemStream.Close();
                         CryptoStream.Close();
                     }
                 }
             }

             SymmetricKey.Clear();
             return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(PlainTextBytes, 0, ByteCount);
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: **I do NOT mean to denigrate MS Access by this**, but is it possibly to simply upgrade to SQL Server or another RDBMS that already has encryption functionality?

Comment: @David Stratton: Well, I have already had some experience on MS Access and I been doing my program for half a month (lol). I don't want to change my mind 2 weeks before my program is due.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely don't encrypt the data and save the encrypted data in the db you will end up with queries like `select field1, field2 from table where field1 = '$WDFV%$:@@{#%SAsdasdh#!fjdkj'` and all your fields would have to be text.  It reptty much defats the object of using an RDBMS.

An access DB can be password protected and encrypted see [this](http://databases.about.com/od/tutorials/ht/Password-Protecting-An-Access-2010-Database.htm) these in instructions are for 2010 but there is also a link to 2007.

However if you are using it as a back end to a winforms gui and you didn't want the user to type it in you would have to store the password somewhere and a determined user would be able to extract it if he/she had the knowledge.

Access is a bad choice if protecting sensitive data from unauthorised users is a priority if it is too late to change at this point in your project then don't use it in future.

Comment: What if I will leave only ID unencrypted? I am searching/deleting only by ID. I can not use network here. File is *.ACCDB. I can not use any servers. And I want to make it as secure as I can. The MOST secure if I can.

Comment: I am creating a file from C# using ADOX and then setting a password to it at this moment. How do I do encryption from C#?

Comment: Encryption works on binary data you will have to turn this into text to store in the database.  All it would take is for your client to say "i want to be able to filter this table by date" and you suddenly have a world of pain.

Comment: Doing cryptography in c# is a very broad topic.  Read up on the types in the system.security.cryptography namespace.

Comment: I have no problems with this scenario, but it's good that you have pointed this out. I am simply adding/deleting data just by ID. I have perfect piece of code which uses salted password to read any text encrypted/decrypted by AES.

Comment: Where is the salted password stored?

Comment: OK so you also never need to sort the data either ?

Comment: No, no sorting necessary. Storing passwords? Well, only at Access file, I suppose. But I want to change that. And if I encrypt file, I am not sure but I'm pretty sure will be used as hash. I will add code to my encryption/decryption file.

Comment: When you say sorting is only required "at access file" then it is sorted by the encrpyted data which is means it will be sorted randomly To sort by an encrpyted field you would have to retreive then entire table into memory decrpyt then sort in code. This will be memory intensive and slow you might as well store the data ina text file rather than access. If the password is in your encrption/decryption file then it can be easily extracted using reflection.

Comment: Well, password isn't stored there. Password is entered by user each time they start the program. I don't see where it's stored. I don't see ho I am retriving a table any other way I would with encrypting fields, trying to support my point. I do need an access only for ID which I would leave unencrypted. I'm sorry, I am trying to think but I am not sure if my thinking is right.

Comment: PS. I have tried earlier to use text file, but I have come up with problems with deleting data. MS Access gives me more abilities here.

Comment: OK if the password is entered by the user then simply use the built in access password and encryption security i link to my post.  That should be pretty hard to crack.

Comment: Yes, I seen this article, but I must be able to create a file from scratch from code, encrypted file from scratch in code. You know where I could refer to?

Comment: Why? just start with an empty encrypted access file

Comment: What if user open my program and not have MS Access installed? I gave an option letting user creating a new file by using ADOX and simple DB password as of right now.

Comment: This is a seperate question but you can just need the access db engine which can be downloaded here http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13255 it can be distributed with your app and installed as part of the installer.  Also include an empty template access db file with all your security already set up.

Comment: Download 400mb package for 80kb program :D Well, I have whole pan of this in my head already working out, but all I need is to secure my file. Thanks for good tips though.

Comment: However you create the access file you need the access db engine to access it.  Consider SQL CE for future projects of this type. it's something like 2mb for the engine requires no installation and can be embedded in your program and can be encrypted.  Access is a toy for use by office monkeys.  Linky: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stevelasker/archive/2008/05/14/security-and-encryption-for-sql-server-compact.aspx