# How easy is to break into MS Access file? How to secure it?

Tags: c#, security, cryptography, ms-access-2007

As person pointed out in [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8333956/720323) it is really easy to break in into MS Access (*.accdc) file.

How people manage to do this? I know they can see the content by using hex editor.

So how do I break into such file other ways? Will people see the password to the database file if file is password protected?

I was planning to have one password for the file, and the use user name and password to encrypt all data but ID in table for security. User name and password will be entered by user.

Should I do this? If not, how can I secure my MS Access file? How do I do this by using C# code only?

Comment: Also note that what you put in C# code won't be a secret either - it can easily be dissambled with ILSpy.  Obfuscation helps.  Keep that in mind for any proposed C# solution.

Comment: @bryanmac: Yes, user name and password must be entered by user.

Comment: 1) Do you need to use MS Access?
2) You can simply purchase a program for cheap, to read access files. I have done it plenty of times to extract data.
3) You need access to the MS file. So security for the actual file is important as well.

Comment: @Michael C. Gates: 1. I do need MS Access file. 2. I'm trying to work with what I have, so not planning to buy anything. 3. Yes, I understand.

Comment: "Secure" is not a binary value; things are not "secure" or "insecure"; they are more or less secure *with respect to a particular threat.*  What is the threat?

Comment: @Eric Lippert: I suppose some one stealing .ACCDB file and trying to crack the file's security to get to the content for variety reasons.

Comment: Security on Access is not great. Database passwords are tissue thin. If you have people getting onto your server who will steal the database, you really have a lot more to worry about than Access security. I have not read about the latest encryttion, but there are some notes here: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/introduction-to-access-2010-security-HA010341741.aspx

Comment: OK, then the *threat* is that the file gets stolen. **Defend against the real threat.** Encrypting a file that might be stolen is a good idea, but *preventing it from being stolen in the first place* is the better solution, so concentrate on that. Don't fall in love with encryption just because it is cool; concentrate on solving the primary security problem. So: who is trying to steal your file, and how can they succeed? Once you've defended against that threat, then start to think about the "security in depth" aspects like what to do to protect the data if they succeed.

Comment: There are many other ways you can defend against this sort of threat as well of course. Two techniques, for example: (1) Make all your secret data public at low cost. There's no impetus to steal something you can buy for cheap. (2) Build honeypots -- fake databases full of fake but realistic data. Make them easy to steal. Thieves will get away with your fake data believing they have the real data. Detect the intrusion on the honeypot, and then get guys with guns to go after the thieves while they still think they have the real data. Note that neither technique requires encryption.

Comment: @Eric Lippert: Great point! I wasn't even thinking that physical security of the file is actually more important than file security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To secure it, you can put the Access DB file in a secure container such as [Truecrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org)

Comment: Kind of too complicated for purpose of my program.

Comment: I think its much simpler than what you were initially planning to do. You just have to create a volume here and put your access file in that volume. Or maybe in your scenario this isn't feasible?

Answer (score 1):

You can protect the file using windows ACLs. Only allow authorized people by locking the file down to a particular list of user ids, or a windows group. Like Eric Lippert said, this won't make it totally secure, you need to decide what will be "secure enough."